# Possible to loop through an array structure in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, data-structures

Apologize ahead of time if this may have been answered previously. Didn't find anything (or wasn't using the correct search terms). Regardless, There is a specific part of my code I wanted to know if I could step through with a loop. I went ahead and added the code below. Two sections that I feel could probably be cleaned up is the request for user input for how much was spent on various budget categories. I had plan to use a for loop, but couldn't figure how to assign values to various elements of the MonthlyBudget structure "currentMonthlyBudget" (i.e. currentMonthlyBudget.housing, currentMonthlyBudget.utilities, etc). It would have worked for the expenseCategories[], but I could find how (or if it is possible) to do it for the structure. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
/* Exercise_10.cpp Monthly Budget Calculation*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct MonthlyBudget
{
    double housing;             //Housing
    double utilities;           //Utilities
    double householdExpense;    //Household Expense
    double transportation;      //Transportation
    double food;                //Food
    double medical;             //Medical
    double insurance;           //Insurance
    double entertainment;       //Entertainment
    double clothing;            //Clothing
    double misc;                //Miscellaneous
};

int main()
{

    //Array of Monthly Budget Values
    double defaultMonthlyBudget[10] = { 500.00, 150.00, 65.00,
                                        50.00, 250.00, 30.00,
                                        100.00, 150.00, 75.00,
                                        50.00 };
    //Array of Expense Categories
    string expenseCategories[10] = { "Housing Accomodations", "Utilities", "Household Expenses",
                                     "Transporation", "Food", "Medical Expenses", "Insurance",
                                     "Entertainment", "Clothing", "Miscellaneous Expenses" };

    //Array to hold the over budget and under budget values
    double actualBudget[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    //Accumulator for actual budget
    double sum = 0.00;
    //Loop counter
    int index;
    //Final Total Budget
    double calculatedTotalBudget = 0.00;

    //Structure
    MonthlyBudget currentMonthlyBudget;

    cout << "Greetings. This program will determine if you are meeting your agreed upon budget." << endl;
    cout << "I will ask you questions about your spending habits, and return a report to see how\n";
    cout << "you did this month. Lets get started!\n\n\n";

    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[0] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.housing;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[1] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.utilities;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[2] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.householdExpense;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[3] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.transportation;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[4] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.food;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[5] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.medical;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[6] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.insurance;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[7] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.entertainment;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[8] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.clothing;
    cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << expenseCategories[9] << ": ";
    cin >> currentMonthlyBudget.misc;
    cout << "\n\n\n";

    //Compare inputted values to those of the predetermine budget
    actualBudget[0] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[0] - currentMonthlyBudget.housing);
    actualBudget[1] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[1] - currentMonthlyBudget.utilities);
    actualBudget[2] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[2] - currentMonthlyBudget.householdExpense);
    actualBudget[3] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[3] - currentMonthlyBudget.transportation);
    actualBudget[4] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[4] - currentMonthlyBudget.food);
    actualBudget[5] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[5] - currentMonthlyBudget.medical);
    actualBudget[6] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[6] - currentMonthlyBudget.insurance);
    actualBudget[7] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[7] - currentMonthlyBudget.entertainment);
    actualBudget[8] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[8] - currentMonthlyBudget.clothing);
    actualBudget[9] = (defaultMonthlyBudget[9] - currentMonthlyBudget.misc);


    //TEST
    /*for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        cout << actualBudget[index] << "\n";
    }*/



    //Add up actualBudget
    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        sum += actualBudget[index];
    }

    //Assign value to Calculated Total Budget
    calculatedTotalBudget = (1420.00 - sum);

    //Loop to display what categories we went over, under, & met our budget
    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        if (actualBudget[index] < 0.00)
        {
            cout << "For the category of " << expenseCategories[index] << ", you went over your budget by $" << abs(actualBudget[index]) << ".\n";
        }
        else if (actualBudget[index] > 0.00)
        {
            cout << "For the category of " << expenseCategories[index] << ", you came in under your budget by $" << abs(actualBudget[index]) << ".\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "For the category of " << expenseCategories[index] << ", you met your budget exactly.\n";
        }
    }


    //Provide information to the user if the grand total went over, under, or met our total budget
    if (calculatedTotalBudget > 1420.00)
    {
        cout << "This month's total expenditure was $" << calculatedTotalBudget << ". You were over budget by $" << (calculatedTotalBudget - 1420.00) << ".\n";
    }
    else if (calculatedTotalBudget < 1420.00)
    {
        cout << "This month's total expenditure was $" << calculatedTotalBudget << ". You were under budget by $" << abs(1420.00 - calculatedTotalBudget) << ".\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "This month's total expenditure was $" << calculatedTotalBudget << ". You met your budget exactly.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to iterate through that struct, why not reinterpret-cast the address of the first element to a double array? You could iterate through that then.

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution could be to just hold a vector of categories and references to the values they map to

```
  //Array of Expense Categories
  std::vector<std::pair<string, double&>> expenseCategories = {
    { "Housing Accomodations", currentMonthlyBudget.housing },
    { "Utilities", currentMonthlyBudget.utilities },
    { "Household Expenses", currentMonthlyBudget.householdExpense },
    { "Transporation", currentMonthlyBudget.transportation },
    { "Food", currentMonthlyBudget.food },
    { "Medical Expenses", currentMonthlyBudget.medical },
    { "Insurance", currentMonthlyBudget.insurance },
    { "Entertainment", currentMonthlyBudget.entertainment },
    { "Clothing", currentMonthlyBudget.clothing },
    { "Miscellaneous Expenses", currentMonthlyBudget.misc } 
  };
```

Any loop will then just use either the category description or the value it maps to

```
for (auto& category : expenseCategories) {
  cout << "\nPlease type in how much was spent this month for " << category.first << ": ";
  cin >> category.second;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/FqnFvb)</kbd>

The solution above has the advantage that you can reorganize your fields as you wish and just update the references involved.

For a simple data structure like the one you have you might as well have referred to its fields as in a simple array (i.e. by getting the pointer to the first element and then iterating over those).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make a for loop from the MonthlyBudget input, you can do it by creating an array of a simple struct:

```
struct BudgetInputInfo {
  std::string message;
  double& targetValue;
}
```

Just create a static array of this, and you can write your for loop based on that array.

You can even add a method to this struct which displays the message, and sets targetValue.

Later, when you have other members than `double`s, you can change this into a `template`.

But I think this won't result in the most readable code, you won't get a real benefit from the for loop, unless you want to be able to change the list it's based on runtime.

If your list is fixed like in the example, creating a function which prints out the message and reads the input would be more readable:

```
void readInput(std::string targetName, double& target) {
  cout << "Please type in how much was spent this month for " << targetName << ": ";
  cin >> target;
  cout << endl;
}
```

With this, you would only have a few relatively short `readInput` calls.

You can even make a function which reads every member of a `MonhtlyBudget`:

```
void readMonhtlyBudget(MonthlyBudget& m) {
  readInput("Housing Accomodations", m.housing);
  // ...
}
```

Also, I would change your 10 element arrays to be instances of `MonthlyBudget`s. It's more clear, and you can even keep your current initializer syntax if you are using C++11:

```
MonthlyBudget defaultBudget =     { 500.00, 150.00, 65.00,
                                    50.00, 250.00, 30.00,
                                    100.00, 150.00, 75.00,
                                    50.00 };
```

And move the difference calculation code into a separate method, preferrable `operator-`:

```
MonthlyBudget operator-(MonthlyBudget const& a, MonthlyBudget const& b) {
  MonthlyBudget result;
  result.housing = a.housing - b.housing;
  // ...
  return result;
}
```

With these changes, you can just write:

```
actualBudget = defaultBudget - currentMonthlyBudget;
```